# Datatable is not printed in combination with cat command in Rmd / RStudio

Tags: r, datatable, knitr, r-markdown

Could someone please explain why in the Rmd code (to generate a HTML report using RStudio) below only the `cat` command is being displayed? When I move the `cat` command outside the `if` clause or comment it out the table is printed. I believe the same thing happens when using `library(printr)`, but I haven't confirmed this with a minimal sample.

It seems that the code inside the `if` clause is somehow interpreted together and that the `cat` doesn't go well with the `datatable`.

If you could give me some clues on how to debug this, it would be helpful, too. As there are no warnings/error messages anywere.

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document
---


```{r}
if(TRUE){
  DT::datatable(iris)
  cat("I am here with my cat")
}

```
````

Comment: Implicit printing does not work inside for loops and if blocks. In these situations, you need to print objects explicitly using `print (object)`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand.... print(DT::datatable(iris)) is not working

Comment: That surprises me. I'll have to look at this when I get to a computer. It may be related to your chunk options. Currently, your code returns console output, and `datatable` may need some help to render correctly

Comment: Extremly interesting. The question can be generalized further: Why does a `asis` chunk with implict printing `DT::datatable(iris)` work, but `print(DT::datatable(iris))` doesn't? (Note that the code in the question works if `cat` is placed before `DT::datatable(iris)` because `if` returns it's last statement, resulting in implicitly printing the datatable.)

Comment: I don't think it is limited to "asis". And for me it doesn't matter if cat is before or after datatable... Also, if I just append "i=1", there is no change either, i.e. the cat still works but not the datatable

Comment: when I store the `DT::datatable` in a variable and print it after the last bracket the table is being printed: `if(TRUE){
  cat("I am here with my cat.")
  mytable=DT::datatable(iris)
 }
mytable`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is essentially the same issue as [knitr#1137](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1137). [HTML widgets](http://htmlwidgets.org), including DT/DataTables, only work when they are generated from *top-level* R expressions. This is because only top-level expressions are actually *printed*. Expressions that are not at the top level are only *evaluated*. There is a big difference between the two cases. Printing involves calling a printing function. In most cases, this function is, not surprisingly, `print()` (or `show()` for S4 objects). In the **knitr** world, it is more complicated than that: the default printing function is `knitr::knit_print`, which is very similar to `print()`, but it does one more thing besides generating the text output, which is collecting the metadata (e.g. HTML dependencies) of the objects being printed. After knitting is done, **rmarkdown** will resolve the meta data into appropriate HTML code (e.g. `<script src="dataTables.js"></script>` in `<head>`).

To sum up, if the expression is not at the top level, neither printing nor metadata collection is done, so there is no way for the widget to be actually rendered.

A simple example to illustrate this:

```
if (TRUE) {

  1:10  # not printed

  11:20 # printed because this is the visible value returned by if()

}
```

Comment: Now I'm curious – would you mind adding a short explanation (or a reference) why this happens?

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on this. I'm still digesting your answer …