# Issue plotting multiple d3heatmaps in conditional with knitr

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, d3heatmap

When trying to plot multiple d3heatmaps within a conditional, the HTML that is generated only plots the final heat map. Below is code for an RMD to reproduce the bug.

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. 

```{r}
require(d3heatmap)
myVar = TRUE
if (myVar == TRUE) {
  d3heatmap(mtcars, col = "Spectral")
  d3heatmap(mtcars, col = "Blues")
}
```
````

If the heat maps are outside of a conditional, multiple will appear in the knitted HTML file. Has anyone else run into this?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] d3heatmap_0.6.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_0.6 magrittr_1.5    htmltools_0.3   tools_3.2.3     base64enc_0.1-3
 [6] yaml_2.1.13     stringi_1.0-1   rmarkdown_0.9.5 knitr_1.12.3    stringr_1.0.0  
[11] digest_0.6.9    evaluate_0.8.3  png_0.1-7
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this goes back to the issue Yihui explains [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35176098/2706569), with the additional trait that `if` returns its last statement. Not sure if the [htmltools::tagList()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35235069/2706569) solution applies in this case. (Update: It does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue is explained in [this answer by Yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194138/2706569): HTML widgets "only work when they are generated from *top-level* R expressions". This explains why wrapping the plots in an `if` statement doesn't work. The second plot is visible nevertheless because `if` returns the value of the last expression evaluated, thus "raising" the last plot to the top level.

As a solution, the plots can be collected in a list and printed via `htmltools::tagList` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235069/2706569):

````
```{r}
require(d3heatmap)
myVar = TRUE
res <- list()
if (myVar == TRUE) {
  res[[1]] <- d3heatmap(mtcars, col = "Spectral")
  res[[2]] <- d3heatmap(mtcars, col = "Blues")
}

htmltools::tagList(res)
```
````

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.