# How can I get Rmarkdown to include a plot from a window opened by a sourced script?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm using Rmarkdown in RStudio and including plots that are opened in new graphics windows. If the window is opened directly in a code chunk, then the plot **is** included in the processed document. But if the window is opened by a separate script that is sourced, then the plot appears during Knitr processing but is **not** included in the document. Here is a complete minimal example of an .Rmd script to demonstrate:

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown graph inclusion"
---

# Make a simple plot:

```{r}
plot(0,0,main="Attempt 1")
```

Result of above: Plot is displayed during processing and is included in generated document.


# Make the plot in a separate graphics window:

```{r}
windows() # open new graphics window; x11() on Linux, MacOS
plot(0,0,main="Attempt 2")
```

Result of above: Plot is displayed during processing and is included in generated document.

# Make the plot in a separate graphics window called from another script:

```{r}
writeLines( "windows() ; plot(0,0,main='From File')" ,
            con="openWindowScript.R" )
source("openWindowScript.R")
```

Result of above: Plot **is** displayed during Knitr processing but is **NOT** included in the generated document. *Why not?*
````

I did search stackoverflow and elsewhere for an answer but didn't find one. Thanks in advance for answers or pointers!

Comment: P.S. Like Thorndike's Cat, I've tried random variations of R functions and Knitr chunk options but without success. Setting `local=TRUE` in `source()` does not work. Various settings of `fig.show` and `fig.keep` in the chunk options also have no effect, at least not for me.

Comment: Are you just looking for *any* way to include a plot that is produced in `openWindowScript.R` (no matter if `source` is used or not) or is sourcing the external file a specific requirement?

Comment: There are pre-existing R scripts that use `windows` (or `x11`) to create plots. I want to run those pre-existing R scripts from a code chunk in Rmarkdown, by `source`ing them because that's how users run the scripts. I don't want to alter the pre-existing R scripts. (I simply want to demonstrate in Rmarkdown the scripts that accompany my textbook. Those scripts `source` other scripts that make plots in new graphics windows.)

Comment: This may be as good of a place as any to ask: why do you need to use `windows`/`x11` in the first place? The `source`ing works fine if you omit that step. One of the first things I did with each of your scripts when I worked through them was to remove those steps (to keep the plot windows where I wanted them, particularly as I use RStudio). Love the book (and examples), but still see the `windows` step as a bit of an idiosyncrasy.

Comment: @Mark: The separate graphics windows are primarily for the cases in which the graphs are only legible with sufficient size and aspect ratio. Then, since doing it for those cases, I just try to be consistent with other cases. (Thanks for your answer below; will check it out soon!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `dev.print()` after the `source` call, it should print the current device (which should, in your case) be the one called by source. This will then be captured by `knit` and included in the document. So, the chunk should look like this:

````
```{r}
writeLines( "windows() ; plot(0,0,main='From File')" ,
            con="openWindowScript.R" )
source("openWindowScript.R")

dev.print()
```
````

I tested this on Linux, which uses X11 for both opening a device and printing it, but the documentation appears to imply that it should work the same on Windows (as long as the Windows specific version of `dev.print` is correctly installed, which it should be by default).

If the `dev.print` is causing issues when run interactively (either just a nuisance or causing a crash), you can block it from running outside of a knit document by checking the name of the file being knit. This returns `NULL` when run interactively, so can be used as a condition in `if` to block execution outside of knitting.

Using the example from the comment about this error, the code chunk becomes:

````
```{r echo=1:2}
writeLines( "windows() ; plot(0,0,main='Ta-Da!')" ,
            con="theScript.R" )
source("theScript.R")

if(!is.null(knitr::current_input())){
  deviceInfo <- dev.print()  
}
```
````

A separate approach is to over-write the behavior of `windows()` (and/or `x11`). At the top of your Rmd document, add

```
x11 <- windows <- function(...){invisible(NULL)}
```

Which should catch all of the calls to `windows` or `x11` and essentially ignore them (the `...` ensures that you shouldn't get "unused argument" errors). If you are using those calls to set size and/or aspect ratio, you would need to use `fig.width` or `fig.height` instead. This may break other things where you actually *want* the behavior of x11/windows, but using `grDevices::x11` (or similar for `windows`) would get you the right function. So, if you are in a pinch, and willing to forgo the reason you used `windows` in the first place, this should work.

Comment: ```{r echo=1:2} \\
writeLines( "windows() ; plot(0,0,main='Ta-Da!')" , con="theScript.R" ) \\
source("theScript.R") \\
# The following `dev.print` is needed only for Rmarkdown to display the plot in the document. Must assign the return value (i.e., name and number of device) to a variable so it is not displayed in the Rmarkdown document. Use `echo=1:N`in r code chunk options, where N is number of lines above this. \\
deviceInfo = dev.print() \\
``` \\
(\\ above means newline) Result of above: Works when Knitr-ed, but *crashes RStudio* when R code is run by itself.

Comment: Does it crash inside RStudio when not saving the result to `deviceInfo`? (If so, setting the chunk option `results='hide'` could be a workaround.) The code, both in my example and yours, does not cause RStudio to crash for me (on Ubuntu though, so may not be comparable). I hate to try the IT cop-out, but did you try closing and re-opening RStudio (to see if it is some other conflict)? In any case, I edited to add a check of whether or not you are knitting (and only run `dev.print` if you are).

Comment: Very nice! But while you're here, one more glitch: When the sourced script opens multiple windows, only the final one is included in the document. For example, \\ ```{r echo=1:2} \\
writeLines( "windows() ; plot(0,0,main='Ta-Da ONE!') ; windows() ; plot(0,0,main='Ta-Da TWO!')" , con="theScript2.R" ) \\
source("theScript2.R") \\
if(!is.null(knitr::current_input())){ deviceInfo <- dev.print() } \\
``` \\ Ideas?

Comment: It looks like `dev.print` (and `dev.copy`) only work on the current device. So, I don't see a path using those. I did add an approach that just overwrites the behavior of `windows`, which should solve the issue through your whole file (and avoid the unnecessary brief popup graphics devices you get while processing the Rmd file).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! (System won't let me award the bounty yet; will do when it's allowed.)

Answer (score 1):

The code suffers from two different issues. One is the code in `openWindowScript.R`, the other is how this file is included into the main document.

The code in `openWindowScript.R` does not even produce a visible plot when used directly as chunk code:

````
```{r}
windows(); plot(0,0,main='From File')
```
````

I think this is due to the difference between top-level expressions and other code (mentioned for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194138/2706569)), but I'm not sure about the details. What *does* produce a visible plot is the following code:

````
```{r}
windows()
plot(0,0,main='From File')
```
````

So with this code in an external file, how could we include it in the document? *Not* by `source`-ing the external file, presumably because then the plotting command again is not a top-level expression. Although Mark Peterson already provided a [nice workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41148894/2706569), I would like to suggest a more `knitr`-idiomatic solution: Inject the code into a chunk, using the [`code` option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#chunk_options):

````
```{r}
writeLines( "windows() \n plot(0,0,main='From File')" ,
            con="openWindowScript.R" )
```

```{r, code = readLines("openWindowScript.R")}
```
````

Comment: Thank you for this interesting answer. The link to the discussion of top-level expressions was revealing, and helps to explain why dev.print() works. I also like the idea of code=readLines() as a chunk option, but  explicitly `source`ing the code is part of the script I want to illustrate in Rmarkdown. Thank you again!

Comment: Just to be clear, on my system the `source`d code with a newline instead of semicolon still does not generate a visible plot in the knitr output -- does it for yours (without the `code` option or my workaround)? I'm also not sure that this is a top-level issue as the plot *is* printed when run interactively (though, such top-level issues often are very important). I had forgotten about `code =` though, so a very good path forward if the workarounds fail. Combining it with `echo = FALSE` and as a separate chunk from where you show the `source` command (with `eval = FALSE`) could work.

Comment: @MarkPeterson `"Just to be clear, on my system the sourced code with a newline instead of semicolon still does not generate a visible plot in the knitr output -- does it for yours (without the code option or my workaround)?"` No, it doesn't.